# Database Migration from SQL Server 2008 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The production server in my company is currently running on SQL Server 2008 Express Edition. Now we want to change the version to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise R2. The server is currently running on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise OS. 
We want to first uninstall the Express Edition on the Server & Install the 2008 R2 Enterprise on it. We don’t prefer the DATABASE UPGRADE option.
Please suggest  how can I go ahead with the installation.

Comment: This is better asked on serverfault.com

Comment: Need info, but you can install Enterprise.  Then detach the database(s) from Express, attach in Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the same server name and instance name (or default, i.e. MSSQLSERVER), you will need to remove the Express instance first.

There are many configuration settings to keep track of - custom listening ports, surface area configuration, master-db collation, logins, roles, permissions, schemas, installed CLR modules etc.  This is not something you will want to attempt with just an answer from ServerFault or StackOverflow.  I sincerely and strongly urge you to hire a consultant for this task.

Of course if you have a very small company running just 1 express database on SQL Server defaults, by all means

- detach the databases
- uninstall express
- install enterprise (using defaults for everything)
- attach the databases

I cannot but re-stress, please **hire a consultant**